# How to add a new option before the last option of a select?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I'm trying to create a new option on the fly and then add it right before the last option of a select.

When I use `$("#select").append("<option>hi</option")`, it always adds after the last one.

How do I add a new option before the last option of a select?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$("select option:last").before("<option>hi</option>");
```

**Online demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6MVEd/

Comment: I have done like above but then also I am not able to get any result.

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#select option").eq(-2).after("<option>hi</option")
```

or

```
$("#select option").eq(-1).before("<option>hi</option")
```

`"#select option"` is a fully valid `querySelectorAll` selector.

Comment: // Thank you for the input. I've learned that I can use eq with select! Thanks!

Comment: @Moon: You're welcome. Yes, it's an easy way to narrow down a matched set of elements to a single one in a jQuery object. The negative index is great for selecting elements from the end.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want the [.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) method.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/

```
$("#select option:last").prev().append("<option>New Option</option>");
```

You may want to avoid using select as an id.